# PHP PDO MySQL Not outputting result but rest of page loads?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to run a different query depending on the amount of results from the table.

I have the following but it only outputs the text at the end, not the 'echo' data?

Can anybody see what Im doing wrong?

```
<?php

require 'dbconfig.php';

class User {

    function checkUser($uid, $oauth_provider, $username, $email, $twitter_otoken, $twitter_otoken_secret) 
    {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' and oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'";

        $result = $DBH->query($query);

        if (!empty($result)) {
                echo 'user';
        } else {
                echo 'no user';
        }

        $DBH = null;

    }

}
?>



Test page loads
```

---

**Calling the class**

On another page I call my class with the below

```
    ...else {
       $twitter_otoken=$_SESSION['oauth_token'];
       $twitter_otoken_secret=$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];
       $email='';
        $uid = $user_info->id;
        $username = $user_info->name;
        $user = new User();
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'twitter', $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret);
        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
 $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
            header("Location: splash.php");
        }
    }
} else {
    // Something's missing, go back to square 1
    header('Location: login-twitter.php');
}
?>
```

**Config**

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbname was here';
$user = 'access';
$pass = 'access';

try {
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    } catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }  

?>
```

Comment: Are you even calling `checkUser` function ? What have you debug so far ?

Comment: You are not using the beauty of PDO. Prepared Statements! This is just another way to make your system vulnerable to SQL Injection.. :(

Comment: where do you create $DBH? You should either use it as class field for example inherited from class or as singleton/registry pattern.

Comment: Its in an included db config file @Robert

Comment: Are there any errors? Maybe you have turned them off in php.ini?  You should use try.. catch and see if there are any exeptions. I agree with @Rikesh you don't seem to create `User` object and call `checkUser` method

Comment: If this is all of your code.. how in the heaven's name did you think you'll ever get something executed? You just specified a class with a function and you never *called* it.

Comment: Your PDO connection `$DBH` is not set inside your class/function, so you are not connected due to variable scope - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You could do one of the following: move your `require 'dbconfig.php';` inside your class function, add it to your function parameters - `function checkUser($DBH,$uid,...)`, add it inside your class and then call it using `$this->DBH`, or call it using `global $DBH` (although most would agree that using global is not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

What it ought to be

config

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbname was here';
$user = 'access';
$pass = 'access';

$opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass, $opt);
```

User

```
class User {

    function checkUser($uid, $oauth_provider) 
    {
        global $DBH;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid=? and oauth_provider=?";
        $stmt  = $DBH->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($uid, $oauth_provider);
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to admit, you felt bad while typing that `global` keyword there :)

Comment: I am still not convinced that calling cat a cat should make whatever particular feeling.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if a statement is empty(), but the result of PDO::query() is a PDOStatement object, not result-data.

To get the data, check out the documentation of [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). You could use something like the [fetchObject()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) method.

Furthermore I would recommend to use PDO's ability to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), instead of a direct query. This would make your application a lot more secure.

This, however, does not explain why it is not working (not working = no echo data in this case). Since it's always an PDOStatement (or **FALSE** in case the query didn't work out), your if statement should just evaluate to TRUE/FALSE. I think it is not this piece of code that's responsible for no output, but as I pointed out above it does have it's flaws.

Comment: Yes you've edited your answer but your answer still is not solving problem and you even mentioned in post that it won't solve his problem.

Comment: True. But there are some fundamental things wrong with his code, that would be just too long to put in a comment.